# openpyxl close read-only workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I can't seem to find a solution to that problem.

How can I close a workboook I opened using openpyxl?

I opened a workbook in read-only mode in order to read the information, not change it.
Now when my code runs it is impossible to save the excel document if someone is using it at the same time. I get the following mistake:

> 'path + filename' is currently in use. Try again later.

The way to close the workbook seems to be `wb.save("filename")`. But this doesn't apply to me because I open it in read-only mode.

What can I do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: open in read-write mode?

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you can't do when. Read-only mode requires that the zip archive is kept open but any file handlers should be garbage collected as soon as the workbook object is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: [OpenPyXL documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html)

`close()`
Close workbook file if open. Only affects read-only and write-only modes.